# Serialize arraylist of Bitmaps

Tags: android, serialization, arraylist

I have a CITEM class:

```
public class CITEM {
    public Bitmap BMP;
    public String DESC;
}
```

In another class I have an array defined as follows:

```
ArrayList<CITEM> array;
```

I need to store the array in a table in a database and had thought of serializing the array. I have two options:

1) A single record with the serialized array.

2) N-Records serializing CITEM objects.

Serializing a Bitmap not a problem but not how to serialize the array. What is the best option? And how I can do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: serialize a bitmap? is it to restore state?

Comment: Yes. Is to restore the state of a puzzle game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not serialize your `CITEM` object since `Bitmap` does not `implements Serializable`. You can encode your bitmap `Base64` and serialize the Base64 strings

Answer (score 0):

I use to Serialize the ArrayList Directly. 
The ArrayList is a Serializable object btw.
All the data kept after you Serialize it or user ObjectOutputStream to save it in file system.
etc, If Bitmap is not a problem.

You can check more information here
[ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

hope that I can help you.